# Can't SSH after logout

Tags: ssh

I have a PC running Ubuntu 18.04 at home which I SSH into while I'm away. Currently, I do this using a port-forward. I know my WAN IP, and I forward port 22 to the static LAN IP of my machine. This works just fine the first time I SSH in, and I can also SSH again, e.g. in a new Terminal tab. However, if I ctrl-d (logout) from one of those tabs, I can't SSH again. The active SSH connections stay active, but I get connection refused on port 22 errors for the other ones. I checked my firewall settings, and there is nothing active. Any ideas why this would happen?

Comment: Could you please check if you use statefull firewall and there is both "new" and "established" connections allowed for ssh connections ?

Comment: @Viktor Thanks for the reply; how do I check that?

Comment: That's belong of what kind of firewall is used. (the device or system that performs nat and forwards packet to your Ubuntu system.

Answer (score 2):

I discovered that this was caused by my Xfinity "Advanced Security" feature. I had to disable it in order to get SSH working normally.

Here's a [link to the Xfinity support article](https://www.xfinity.com/support/articles/using-xfinity-xfi-advanced-security) that helped me turn it off.

Comment: @user68186 I added a link to the support article I used, which has some screenshots. Unfortunately, I'm stuck with the modem because they don't let you use your own if you want the unlimited plan with 1GiB download speed.